# Affine Bundles vs Affine Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, affine-geometry

I went through the wiki article on affine spaces and had a quick look on the affine bundle wiki article but I don't understand what the affine map is in the case of affine bundles over vector bundles. Can somebody give a quick explanation? Thx alot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that a set $A$ is an affine space "modeled" on a vector space $V$ if it is equipped with a free transitive action of $V$ (with respect to its abelian group structure). The action of a vector $v\in V$ on $a\in A$ is denoted by $a+v$.

An affine map between two affine spaces $A_1, A_2$, modeled on the same vector space $V,$  is a map which commutes with  the $V$-actions.

For example, you can check that if $A$ is an affine space modeled on $V$, then for each $v\in V$, $a\mapsto a+v$ is an affine map $A\to A$, and all affine maps $A\to A$ are of this form.

Also, any vector space $V$ can be considered as an affine space over itself, in an obvious way, and all affine spaces modeled on $V$ are isomorphic to this example.

We say that a fiber bundle $\mathcal A\to M$ is an affine bundle modeled on a vector bundle $\mathcal V\to M$ if for each $x\in M$, $\mathcal A_x$ (the fiber of $\mathcal A$ over $x$) is an affine space modeled on the vector space $\mathcal V_x$ (there are also some obvious regularity assumptions, like continuity, smoothness, local triviality, etc, depending on the context).

If you have two affine bundles over some manifold, modeled on the same vector bundle, you can now easily define, fiber by fiber, what is an affine map between them.

All this sounds quite trivial, so the point is to find some interesting examples that justify this formalism.  My time is up, but perhaps some other participants of this forum (or you yourself) can supply us with such examples.

Comment: So especially every vector bundle is an affine bundle modeled over itself. If there is moreover a connection on the vector bundle when do we consider that as an affine connection?

Comment: So for example the trivial fiber bundle $\mathbb{S}\times M$ modeled over the trivial vector bundle $\mathbb{R}\times M$ with the affine map $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is an affine bundle?

Comment: Every connection on a vector bundle will also be a connection of the associated affine bundle.

Comment: @Freeze_S: An affine  connection is, by definition, a connection on the tangent bundle of a manifold. The reason for this name is that the parallel transport of such a connection  extends naturally to an *affine* map between the fibers. One way to "see" this extension is by drawing a curve along a convex surface (eg a sphere), lay a piece of cardboard tangent to the surface at one end of the curve, then roll it along the curve without slipping or twisting; this defines an affine map between the tangent spaces at the end points of the curve.